# Stick footer to bottom (when shown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**OK, so let me explain what I'm trying to do :**

- I've got a basic footer, at the bottom of each page
- I don't want it appear *all* the time
- The footer has to appear when the page has been scrolled all the way down, and even then at the bottom-most part of the page (not after the contents, but where the window border ends)

**Let's take this as an example :**

- A very short page : the footer does show up, at the bottom of the contents. I want it shown **at bottom of the window**.
- A long page : the footer goes after the end of the contents.

How is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used the solution from http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ .

**CSS:**

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hmmm... Well, this definitely *does* cause the footer to stick. But it does so, *all* the time. I mean if I shrink the window, it just becomes a sticky footer and overlaps my content...

Comment: It doesn't overlaps the content.. have you tried it?

Comment: Yup, I have. Give me a sec to check that Bootstrap doesn't previously set any properties that cause it not to work...

Comment: You must assure that you changed the margin of the .wrapper according with the height of the footer in order to not overlap the content

Comment: Well, OK. There were some things messing up - but I finally got it working. Thanks to you. Great solution. Spot on! :-)

Answer (score -2):

if you add css to footer `#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}`
footer will be at bottom of page